# How to map a world that changes continuously?

Tags: creature-design, map-making, navigation

This world is made of living creatures instead of land. Many, small or big, some as big as Scotland, moving around the world.

What they eat doesn't matter, how they are alive doesn't matter.

The question is: How to map a world that changes continuously?

You could have your home in a valley, the next year that same valley with your house moves to the opposite pole. Imagine them like the pieces of a puzzle that always change place.

They reproduce but the population is stable, fixed actually.

So let's say you live in this world and you need to visit someone in another country, guess what... That other country just moved away so you need a way to find it. There's no internet or satellites.

Comment: @PcMan they "leave" man. Scotland has been seen on its way off the Canary islands. England is still crying over it.

Comment: Are there any trends in the movement, or it's totally chaotic? If former, an appropriate mapping system can be developed. If latter, mapping would be worse than weather reports.

Comment: What's the technology level? If it's modern age or if there is magic you could have a self-updating map of some kind like a modern GPS.

Answer (score 1):

You don't map the whole world statically. You map it locally if creatures do not change shape much in time.

Then the next think you do is figuring out their feeding and migration patterns. This way you can have a general idea of where the creatures will be at certain parts of the week, month and year - and then do their migration map. That's a best effort shot at it, though.

It's kinda like electron orbitals. They tell you where you are most likely to find an electron, but it doesn't mean it will necessarily be there.

---

In a world like this, cartography is sure to develop new branches. *Migratographers* would specialize in tracking the creatures' movement across time, cataloguing this information in a way that other people may use to plan their routes and travels. And people with vast experience in traveling through many different places could be useful in telling you where you most likely are if the creature is out of its usual zones.

Answer (score 1):

**Coordinates.**

[image: latitude and longitude coordinates]

https://www.britannica.com/science/latitude

We are familiar with GPS coordinates but coordinate systems have been used for a long time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system

> The invention of a geographic coordinate system is generally credited
> to Eratosthenes of Cyrene, who composed his now-lost Geography at the
> Library of Alexandria in the 3rd century BC.[3] A century later,
> Hipparchus of Nicaea improved on this system by determining latitude
> from stellar measurements rather than solar altitude and determining
> longitude by timings of lunar eclipses, rather than dead reckoning.

The problem faced by persons on your mutable world is similar to that faced by seafarers out of sight of land, or travelers far from their familiar landmarks.  If you cannot use landforms to orient yourself you can use the movement of celestial objects like the sun and stars.  You can take sightings of those and determine where you are on the globe.  I can share my coordinates with you and then it does not matter if my house is on a mountain or in a deep hole; you can find me.

Answer (score 0):

If the places are mixing evenly, there should be a common language. In this case some kind of signaling (lighthouses, bonfires) could be used to distribute location information. There needs to be specially trained personal in every area to assemble a map. Alternatively one could replace signaling with messengers who are continuously symchronizing the maps with the neighbours.